# Netty setRadable() under the hood

Tags: sockets, netty

The netty javadoc explains that setReadable suspends/resumes the read operation of the I/O thread. My question is what is happening with the data in the meanwhile.
Let's say I run setReadable(false) on a channel of a server, and the client on the other side is writing data to the socket, where does the data go? will it fill some buffer? Is there a way I can control this buffer or get any notifications when it overflows?

> Suspends or resumes the read operation of the I/O thread
>   asynchronously. This method is a shortcut to the following code:
>
> int interestOps = getInterestOps();  if (readable) {
>        setInterestOps(interestOps | OP_READ);  } else {
>        setInterestOps(interestOps & ~OP_READ);  }

It is worth mentioning that if you call setReadable(false) on a channel that already has some data to dispatch you will get the data.
So If you call setReadable(false) inside channelOpen in one of your handlers you will still get messageReceived on that tunnel if the client write just as it connects.
[as explained on this issue](https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/214)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It removes the interested ops for reading from then Channel. This means that the os will need to buffer everything in the network stack. Once this buffer is full new packets get discarded.

How you adjust this buffer is specific to the operation system. On linux you can do it via the /proc fs.

Comment: Yeah and I can see it buffering with netstat,  If after a while I setReadble(true) on that channel, it supposed to read it from the OS buffer again?